# Get Request to Third Party API(Coinbase API) Fails in .NET Core, It works with curl

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient, coinbase-api

I am trying to send a get request to a third-party API using **HttpClient**. However, I keep getting 400. The request succeeds with curl. Is this something related to headers?

```
 using (var client = new HttpClient())

 {
                                              
      string endpoint = "https://api.exchange.coinbase.com/products/BTC-USDT/trades/?limit=100";
      var response = await client.GetAsync(endpoint);
      Console.WriteLine(response); //Bad Request
      ....
 }
```

The response I am getting:

```
StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionResponseContent, Headers:
{
  Date: Mon, 06 Feb 2023 19:10:26 GMT
  Connection: keep-alive
  CF-Cache-Status: DYNAMIC
  Server: cloudflare
  CF-RAY: 79562f95dcce0531-OTP
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
  Content-Length: 44
}
```

With the command below, I get a valid response:

```
curl -X "GET" "https://api.exchange.coinbase.com/products/BTC-USDT/trades/?limit=100"
```

Comment: Compare the requests with Fiddler or an HTTP echo service.

Comment: is there any content you are getting in the response?

Comment: You should provide more information about the endpoint you want to access, not just "it's not working".   In this case, you should at least provide the curl query.

Comment: The response.Content is {"message":"User-Agent header is required."} ;) Add `client.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.Add(new ProductInfoHeaderValue(new ProductHeaderValue("smgtkn")));`

Comment: The error actually tells you what to do. `curl` probably adds that header automatically. That header tells the server what browser is used.

Comment: curl adds the user agent as “curl/version″ currently “curl/7.87.0”